# OpenCV Android samples on Samsung Note 3

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to get the OpenCV Android samples to run on my Note 3.  I get this error in logcat, and just a black screen on my Note 3 when I try to run any of them:

```
12-08 17:29:38.822: E/OpenCV_for_Tegra(15482): Canot create OpenGL context
```

Pretty sure I have everything setup right, SDK, NDK, OpenCV and OpenCV app from Google Play.

Looks like others are having same problem:  http://answers.opencv.org/question/23646/failed-to-run-demos-on-galaxy-note-3/

Anyone know a work around or status of fix?  I can't seem to follow any of those link, maybe the OpenCV issues server is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73893565/OpenCV_2.4.8pre_Manager_2.16_armv7a-neon.apk

Please install this and try again.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not try your apk, but I recently upgraded the opencv app from Google Play and it works  on my Note 3 now.

Answer (score 1):

The file of the link is missing. In a Note 4, I installed the OpenCV Manager (ended with `android8` in the file name) from the APK present in the OpenCV SDK and it works just fine!

For the OpenCV 2.4.X the folder and file is:

```
OpenCV-2.4.X-android-sdk/apk/OpenCV_2.4.X_Manager_2.19_armv7a-neon-android8.apk
```